# Select items from ASP.NET collections by percentage

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I have a collection contains let say 100 items.

```
Collection<int> myCollection = new Collection<int>();

for(int i; i <= 100; i++)
{
    myCollection .Add(i);
}
```

How can i randomly select items by percentage(eg. 30%) from this collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rand = new Random();
var top30percent = myCollection.OrderBy(x=> rand.Next(myCollection.Count))
                               .Take((int)(0.3f*myCollection.Count)).ToList();
```

You can remove the `ToList()` if you want some deferred query.

Comment: Only problem with this though is that its possible that the same item could be selected more than once. Which may or may not be okay, depending on the OPs needs

Comment: Nice! Yes, I need avoid the same item being selected more than once.

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts in your question. First, you must shuffle your collection in order to select items randomly. To shuffle it, you can do it properly with the Fisher-Yates shuffle, or just order your items using a pseudo-random generator.

The Fisher-Yates shuffle comes from [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/2316200) :

```
public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  

    return list;
}
```

However, I'm returning the list so we can use it cleanly with the take part.
Also, if you don't really need to shuffle cleanly, you can use a simple [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with either `i => random.Next()` or `i => Guid.NewGuid()` as the lambda expression.

Secondly, once it's shuffled, now you need to take a percentage of items. You can do this simply by using the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) LINQ method.

Like the Shuffle method, you can make it as an Extension method :

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TakePercentage(this IList<int> list, int percentage)
{
    return list.Take(percentage * list.Count / 100);
}
```

If you prefer receiving a decimal (e.g. 0.3) directly :

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TakePercentage(this IList<int> list, double percentage)
{
    return list.Take((int)(percentage * list.Count));
}
```

Finally, to use it, it's quite simple :

```
var thirtyPercent = myCollection.Shuffle().Take(30);
```

Comment: Nice. But the same items will be selected more than once, right?